# Inserting apostrophes into mysql database

Tags: mysql, insert, apostrophe

I have a CSV file structured on three text columns. Let's call them column A, B, C. In column A, I have free text that might include on several rows apostrophes.

I would like to create a mysql table that includes all the rows in the CSV file. How should I handle the apostrophes?

P.S. To create the mysql table, I plan to create insert queries using excel formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the web-site:

> There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:
>
> A “'” inside a string quoted with “'” may be written as “''”.
>
> A “"” inside a string quoted with “"” may be written as “""”.
>
> Precede the quote character by an escape character (“\”).
>
> A “'” inside a string quoted with “"” needs no special treatment and
>   need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, “"” inside a string
>   quoted with “'” needs no special treatment.

So either use two apostrophes or precede with  backslash.

EDIT: I see you say you are using Excel. I can tell you from experience it gets really confusing with the quote characters, especially as two single quotes can look like a double quote. It is probably better to use the backslash option in that case.

Comment: So basically, I just need to do a replace all apostrophes with backslash apostrophes and then run the inserts.

Comment: Yep - seems like a plan.